# DRF: how to call a serializer (as a nested serializer field) before it is defined?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  b = Bserializer()
  ...

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  ...
```

I need to call BSerializer before it is defined. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  def __init__(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(instance, **kwargs)
      self.fields['b'] = BSerializer()

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  ...
```